# HackerRank: Connected Cells in a Grid

Tags: python, matrix, depth-first-search

I'm trying to solve the HackerRank problem "Connected Cells in a Grid".
Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/connected-cell-in-a-grid/problem?isFullScreen=true

I have written a code for this problem and 5 out of 7 test cases are passing

Failing test case:

```
Input (stdin)
5
5
0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 1
0 1 1 1 0

Expected Output
15
```

My code

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'connectedCell' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY matrix as parameter.
#

def connectedCell(matrix):
    # Write your code here
    def markNeighborsVisited(i, j, regionLen):
        if i < 0 or j < 0 or i >= len(matrix) or j >= len(matrix[0]) or matrix[i][j] == 0:
            return
        
        regionLen += 1
        matrix[i][j] = 0
        
        markNeighborsVisited(i-1, j, regionLen)
        markNeighborsVisited(i-1, j+1, regionLen)
        markNeighborsVisited(i-1, j-1, regionLen)
        
        markNeighborsVisited(i, j+1, regionLen)
        markNeighborsVisited(i, j-1, regionLen)
        
        markNeighborsVisited(i+1, j, regionLen)
        markNeighborsVisited(i+1, j+1, regionLen)
        markNeighborsVisited(i+1, j-1, regionLen)
        
        # store the max value -- we are using a list because a list variable act as a object and if we change anything in list in sub method then the list will be modified automatically outside this sub method
        largestRegion[0] = max(largestRegion[0], regionLen)
        

    largestRegion = [0]
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            if matrix[i][j] == 1:
                markNeighborsVisited(i, j, 0)
    
    return largestRegion[0]
                    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    n = int(input().strip())

    m = int(input().strip())

    matrix = []

    for _ in range(n):
        matrix.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

    result = connectedCell(matrix)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Can someone please help me with failing test case?

Comment: Please use a minimum reproducible example as it helps others answer your question faster.

Comment: Your bug is subtle. `regionLen` is tracking the length of the longest depth-first path in the region, which is not necessarily the total region size.  You need a way to tally _all_ of a region's pixels.  I will not spoil the joy you'll feel when you get it working by giving you code.